# Multiple Output To DataGridView Using Recursion

Tags: windows, vb.net, forms, datagridview, subdirectory

[image: MINI PROJECT BROWSER]

I have been struggling for days trying to find a way to insert my data into a multiple column DataGridView using a DataTable. I'm not sure if recursion is the best or most efficient way? But, so far it is what works to not throw folder access exceptions when accessing system or special folders, etc.

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO**

I'm working on a personal project to create what I call a Mini Project Browser which retrieves data about my Visual Studio projects from the Source > Repos folder and other stuff as well. I already managed to retrieve the data I want initially from each of my project folders using recursion. But I don't know how to input this into the DataTable (i.e. into the correct columns or as rows) to output it to the DataGridView?

I am using the following three calls (which all work independently) to the same sub routine to get all the *.sln, *.Form1.vb and *.exe files (not all executables, just the project exec files):

```
GetFiles("*.sln", "C:\Users\<username>\source\repos", 10, 0)

GetFiles("Form1.vb", "C:\Users\<username>\source\repos", 10, 0)

GetFiles("*.exe", "C:\Users\<username>\source\repos", 10, 0)
```

**REPOS FOLDER SUB ROUTINE**

```
'REPOS (recursive) SUB:
Public Sub GetFiles(ByVal strFileFilter As String, ByVal strDirectory _
      As String, ByVal intDepthLimit As Integer, ByVal intCurrentDepth As Integer)

    Try
        Dim folderInfo As New DirectoryInfo(strDirectory)

                    If intCurrentDepth < intDepthLimit Then
            Dim directories() As DirectoryInfo
            directories = folderInfo.GetDirectories()

            For Each fDirectory In directories
                
           GetFiles(strFileFilter, fDirectory.FullName, intDepthLimit, intCurrentDepth + 1)
                'NumericUpDown1.Value = intCurrentDepth.ToString

                Label9.Text = fDirectory.FullName.Count.ToString

            Next

        End If

        Dim files() As FileInfo
        files = folderInfo.GetFiles(strFileFilter)

        For Each fFile In files
            ListBox1.Items.Add(fFile.FullName)
            Label11.Text = fFile.FullName.Count.ToString
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

**THE PROBLEM**

So, in the sub routine the data from the repos subfolders is input into a listview (it could be input into any control or maybe an array?). I call this same sub three times to get the file lists I need. Currently, I pass the data from each call to another listbox (i.e. Call 1 (*.sln): ListBox1 > ListBox2, then clear ListBox1. Call 2 (*.Form1.vb): Listbox1 > Listbox3, then clear ListBox1. Call 3 (*.exe): ListBox1 > ListBox4). I'm just using the ListBox controls because I still can't seem to find a way to split the almost 300 rows in each result adding them as rows into the three DataTable columns and then displaying them in the DataGridView using the DataTable as the DataSource?

I have managed to get the first column populated with the items from the first ListBox. But when I try to add the items from the second ListBox into the second column I just get a single row?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

The first snippet I tried (as follows) works, but I can only seem to get it working to populate the first column?

```
    For index As Integer = 0 To FirstNameListBox.Items.Count - 1  
 table.Rows.Add( {FirstNameListBox.Items(index), LastNameListBox.Items(index) })  
 Next index
```

Then, I tried inventing something on my own (below), but the results are the same. Either I get all the items from the ListBox as a single row in the DataGridView or I can only populate the first column and on the second column all the items from the second ListBox are 'glued' together in a single row?

```
    'ADD COLUMNS TO DGV/DATATABLE???
        dtPROJ.Columns.Add("SLN", GetType(String))
        dtPROJ.Columns.Add("FORM1.VB", GetType(String))
        dtPROJ.Columns.Add("EXE", GetType(String))

        'ADD NEW DATA TO DATATABLE TO UPDATE DGV:
        Dim dr As DataRow = dtPROJ.NewRow
               
'CALL REPOS FOLDER SUB-ROUTINE:
GetFiles("*.sln", "C:\Users\<username>\source\repos", 10, 0)

    'POPULATE LISTBOX WITH RESULTS:
        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items)

    'CREATE LIST FROM LISTBOX ITEMS:
        Dim lst As New List(Of String)
        For Each item As String In ListBox2.Items
            lst.Add(item)
        Next

    'CLEAR FIRST LISTBOX:
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    'GET LIST ITEMS:
        Dim sResult As String = ""

        For Each elem As String In lst
            sResult &= elem & " "
            RichTextBox4.Text = elem

        'SPLIT ITEMS, ADD TO RICHTEXTBOX, ADD TO DATATABLE:
            For Each line In RichTextBox4.Lines
                'Dim parts = line.Split(Chr(13))
                'dr = dtPROJ.NewRow
                dr(0) = dtPROJ.Rows.Add(line.Trim)
            Next
        Next
```

**RESULTS I EXPECT**

[image: MINI PROJECT BROWSER]

I don't really care too much about which code approach is used. I need to access system and special folders which often deny access throwing an access exception. This recursive approach works up to the point where I get lost because for each kind of filepath I want to retrieve from from the main folder I need to make a separate call to the sub routine above. How do I call *.sln, *.Form1.vb and *.exe (getting only the path to the program executable in bin\Debug folder which contains 2 exec files) and then add these to Columns 1, 2, 3 respectively of the DataTable? Each call gives me a list of almost 300 filenames for each extension. e.g. C:\Users<username>\source\repos\ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\Debug\Filename.exe? The *.sln files are in the top level main folder for each project. The Form1.vb files are in a second level folder for each project. The *.exe files I'm interested in are four levels deep in the bin\Debug folder.

I really would appreciate help on this because I have searched and tried for days and I'm not getting anywhere! I'm sure there must be an easier, more direct way of doing this?